# Vue watchers and reactivity

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity, vue-script-setup

In my vue app, I want to watch route changes, and then react to the change. Here is an example where I simulate a route change.

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, watch } from 'vue'
  import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'
  const router = useRouter()
  const route = useRoute()

  // simulating a route change
  setTimeout(() => {
    router.push('/teams/t2')
  }, 2000);

  // Example 1 (doesn't work)
  watch(route.params.teamId, (newValue, oldValue) => {
    console.log(oldValue, newValue)
  })

  // Example 2 (works!)
  watch(() => route.params.teamId, (newValue, oldValue) => {
    console.log(oldValue, newValue)
  })
</script>
```

In example 1, I want to watch for changes of the route parameter **teamId**, so I pass **route.params.teamId** to the watcher, and I get a warning in the console saying *"Invalid watch source:  t2 A watch source can only be a getter/effect function, a ref, a reactive object, or an array of these types."* And of course, my console.log doesn't fire.

If I simply pass **route** to the watcher, I don't get this warning. But the Vue Router documentation says *"The route object is a reactive object, so any of its properties can be watched and you should avoid watching the whole route object. In most scenarios, you should directly watch the param you are expecting to change"*

What I get from it is that **route** is a reactive object, but **route.params.teamId** is not. But why does using **() => route.params.teamId** work fine then? I don't understand the difference between passing the value, and using an anonymous arrow function to return that same value, and what makes one result reactive, and the other not.

Comment: Not specific to Vue. There's no way how watch could be implemented in JS when passing a value to a function, `watch(route.params.teamId` is the same as `watch('t2'`. You cannot read teamId multiple times inside watch without a function

Comment: To complement previous comment, a reactive object such as objects returned by the ref or reactive methods use properties with getters/setters under the hood, so passing those is similar to passing functions. This is best explained [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals#why-refs)

Comment: As a Vue developer, I am curious why you need to do this. When the route changes, the onMounted code should fire again. If it isn't, you have other issues. Which version of Vue are you using?

Comment: @recoilnetworks excellent question! In this example, I have a component <TeamMembers /> showing members of a team. When viewing team one (/teams/t1), <TeamMembers /> is displayed. Then, if you decide to programatically navigate to /teams/t2 from /teams/t1, you're still calling the exact same TeamMembers component, and it will not update, although your route has changed, and the data you need to display has changed. This was actually an example for a Vue.js course I was doing, and this exact behavior was one of the "gotchas". Let me know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize my question was quite stupid. I somehow assumed that whatever you give to watch() will be magically tracked somehow. It slipped my mind that we actually always give the watcher reactive properties.

For those still wondering about the function gives us "fresh" values, here's a basic example:

```js
    let numOne = 3; let numTwo = 1;
    let sum = numOne + numTwo;
    let getSum = () => { return numOne + numTwo }
    console.log(sum) // returns 4
    console.log(getSum()) // returns 4
    numTwo = 2;
    console.log(sum) // returns 4
    console.log(getSum()) // returns 5
```

sum has a value that was set when it was declared.
getSum() grabs the values at the moment it is called.